# MariaDB prepareStatement does not convert characterSet for where clause

Tags: java, jdbc, mariadb

I have a problem here which looks like a bug in MariaDB to me, but before posting it to the MariaDB bug database I wanted to post it here, maybe I am doing something wrong.

The problem can easily be reproduced with the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ReplicationException, SQLException {
  byte[] cb3 = {-61, -92, 98, -29, -125, -70, -61, -87}; //equals to "äb?é", with “?” being a japanese character
  String corrupt = new String(cb3, Charsets.UTF_8);
  MariaDB db = new MariaDB();
  Connection conn = db.getConnection();

  //byte[] latinBytes =  corrupt.getBytes(Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1")); //workaround
  //corrupt = new String(latinBytes, Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1")); //workaround

  PreparedStatement sqlInsert = conn.prepareStatement("insert into prep values (?)");
  sqlInsert.setString(1, corrupt);
  sqlInsert.execute();
  conn.commit();
  System.out.println("insert ok");

  PreparedStatement sqlSelect = conn.prepareStatement("select * from prep where text=? ");
  sqlSelect.setString(1, corrupt);
  sqlSelect.execute();
}
```

On my MariaDB (which has character set latin1!), there is a table prep: "create table prep (text varchar(10));"
When i run this code, the insert works perfectly: the japanese character gets converted to "?", as expected.
However, the sqlSelect doesnt work at all and yields the feared error message "Illegal mix of collations (latin1_general_cs,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '='".

If I change the sql to "select * from prep where text=? collate latin1_general_cs", I get the error message "COLLATION 'latin1_general_cs' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'utf8'". Therefore i concluded that my bind variable "corrupt" was not converted to latin1 for the where clause. However, I expected this conversion because it worked with the insert.

There is a working workaround: if you activate the two lines "//workaround", the String will be converted in java before giving it to the database. However, I feel that this should not be neccessary.

Running the same code on an oracle database yields no error. Can somebody run this on a mysql database?

So, does this look like a bug to you, or am I missing something.

Additional infos:
MariaDB version 10.0.14, MariaDB Client Library for java: 1.1.7
The jdbc connection string looks like this:

```
"jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/myDb?rewriteBatchedStatements=true&useServerPrepStmts=false"
```

To start the database I use the default "my-large.ini".
I created the database with this code:

```
create database myDb
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 
COLLATE latin1_general_cs;
```

Update: I submitted a bug report to the mariaDB team:
https://mariadb.atlassian.net/browse/CONJ-117

Comment: I just tested your code against MySQL 5.6.13 using MySQL Connector/J 5.1.26 and it ran fine without having to enable the workaround.

Comment: ...and just now I tested it with MariaDB 10.0.13 and MariaDB Java Client 1.1.7 but the `sqlInsert.execute();` statement fails with *"java.sql.SQLDataException: Incorrect string value: '\xE3\x83\xBA\xC3\xA9' for column 'text' at row 1"*. `prep.text` is `varchar(10)` with collation `latin1_general_ci` (as it was for my MySQL test). If you can suggest how I might tweak my MariaDB test case to get past that please let me know.

Comment: Thanks for trying this out. I am not sure why the MariaDB test case doesnt work. So I am providing more info about that testcase by editing my original post...

Comment: It does not work, because what you are trying to insert "non-latin1" characters into latin1 column. MariaDB JDBC uses UTF8. Server notices it cannot convert. this is what it is telling. That ConnectorJ succeeds a pure luck, and if you would run it with UTF8, you'll get the same result. You'd need a UTF8 column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After experimenting with your test code using both MariaDB and MySQL I can confirm that they do seem to behave differently. However, I wouldn't necessarily call it a "bug" in MariaDB.

It appears to be a difference in the response from the database server itself. I tried applying the changes to a MariaDB 10.0.13 server using both the MariaDB Java Client 1.7 and the MySQL Connector/J 5.1.27 and they both gave the same result: MariaDB was able to automagically translate the first, second and fourth characters from UTF-8 to Latin1, but it choked on the third (Japanese) character U+30FA (0xE3 0x83 0xBA in UTF-8) because there is no Latin1 equivalent.

That makes sense. In some cases it might be convenient for MySQL to simply (and silently) map all un-translatable characters to `'?'` but that may not always be desirable. What you have devised as a workaround is telling Java to explicitly force non-Latin1 characters to `'?'` and then passing *that* to MariaDB. You feel that it should not be necessary, but I'm not sure I agree.

So, whether it is a "bug" in MariaDB really depends on whether MariaDB operating *"as designed"*. In other words, just because MariaDB behaves differently than MySQL does not necessarily make it a bug in MariaDB. For example in MariaDB 5.5.31 they changed the behaviour of [CAST()](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/documentation/functions-and-operators/string-functions/cast/) to fix a problem in the interpretation of binary string literals, the result being

> This introduces an incompatibility with previous versions of MariaDB, and all versions of MySQL

That said, you could always report your issue as a MariaDB bug and see how they respond.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will report the issue and provide the link.